# What does this 2 line of code mean ( *from a tutorial )?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am trying to understand the way functions are called in this tutorial
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#SQLResultSetList

(* I tried googling about call back function but still don't get these )

1. at the end there is `db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);` does that mean it will call function populateDB and if it fails it call errorCB and if it success it call successCB ? or what are the sequence of the function calls ?
2. Then upper to that there is `tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);`
      What does  [ ] mean ? And again what is the sequence of function called as now querySuccess is before errorCB ( unlike the Q1. case ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes it will execute populateDB, then successCB on success, and errorCB on error
2. [] means empty array, and again by their names it looks like querySucces will be execute on success, and errorCB on error,

but check the api documentation for those functions ([transaction](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/#dom-database-transaction) and [executeSql](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/#dom-sqltransaction-executesql)) to see what each argument is for, it should tell you the purpose of each argument

Comment: Really thanks alot. That was exactly the page i wanted and been googling.  But never get it. I google for "executeSql" and "sqlite executeSql" and "phonegap executeSql" . But that page never showed up .